# New to discrete mathematics - Disjunctive normal form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, disjunctive-normal-form

I just started a Discrete mathematics course and i really need help with one of the exercises. It may not be very difficult, but i am really having a hard time understanding what i should do. Of course i have checked the answer-list in back of the book but unfortunately the exercise is not contained. I am the kind of kind who can not think of anything else than a problem i can not solve, so here i am.

Here is the exercise:

"Suppose that a truth table in *n* propositional values is specified. Show that a compound proposition with this truth table can be formed by taking the disjunction of conjunctions of the variables or their negations, with one conjunction included for each combination of values for which the compound proposition is ture. The resulting compound proposition is said to be in **disjunvtive normal form**."

To be honest i had a hard time reading it the first time, but now i am trying to do exactly what the exercise says, but i guess my level is to low yet, to completely understand it.

Suppose i have two propositional values, *p*, *q* and their truth tables, how should i proceed from that ( if that is possible? )

Edit:

Suppose this is my truth table of p an q:
p q 
 
t t 
t f 
f t 
f f

Kind regards Chris

Comment: Formula $\mathcal A$ "made with" the prop letters $P,Q$. Build the truth table: 2 letters means $2^2=4$ rows.

Comment: Some row of the t-t evaluate to TRUE, some to FALSE. Consider the rows evaluated to TRUE. For each of them build the conjunction $A_1 \land A_2$ where $A_1$ is $P$ if in that row $P$ is evaluated to TRUE and is $\lnot P$ if in that row $P$ is evaluated to FALSE. And the same for $A_2$.

Comment: Call the above conjunction $\mathcal C_j$ where $\mathcal C_j$ corresponds to the $j$-th row in the t-t.

Comment: Now consider the $\mathcal C_j$ corrsponding to the rows evaluated to TRUE and build a disjunction $\mathcal D$ with them; i.e. $\mathcal C_1 \lor \ldots$.

Comment: Finally, check with the corresponding tuth tables that $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal D$ are equivalent.

Comment: Ok; we have the base for the t-t, but we need a formula, like e.g. $p \to q$ in order to "run a test case".

Comment: If we have $p \to q$, the corresponding columns of the t-t will be: t,f,t,t.

Comment: Thus, according to the procedure above, we have to build the formula $\mathcal D = \mathcal C_1 \lor \mathcal C_3 \lor \mathcal C_4$, where $\mathcal C_j$ corresponds to the row evaluated to TRUE (1st, third and fourth).

Comment: $\mathcal C_1$ will be: $p \land q$, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a concrete example:

Suppose we have the following truth-table ($P * Q$ is some arbitrary formula involving atomic propositions $P$ and $Q$):

\begin{array}{cc|c}
P & Q & P * Q\\
\hline
T & T & T\\
T & F & T\\
F & T & F\\
F & F & T\\
\end{array}

Note that the formula is true in rows 1,2, and 4.  In row 1, $P$ and $Q$ are both true, so we generate the corresponding expression $P \land Q$.  In row 2, $P$ is true and $Q$ is false, so we generate the term $P \land \neg Q$.  Row 4 corresponds to $\neg P \land \neg Q$.

If we now disjunct all these terms together, we get:

$$(P \land Q) \lor (P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P \land \neg Q)$$

Now see what happens if we put this expression back on a truth-table:

\begin{array}{cc|c|c|c|c}
P & Q & P \land Q & P \land \neg Q & \neg P \land \neg Q & (P \land Q) \lor (P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P \land \neg Q)\\
\hline
T & T & T & F & F & T\\
T & F & F & T & F & T\\
F & T & F & F & F & F\\
F & F & F & F & T & T\\
\end{array}

Note how each of the disjuncts is true in exactly the one row that it was generated from, and thus how the disjunction is true in exactly those rows where the original expression $P * Q$ is true. Thus, we can describe $P * Q$ with the formula $(P \land Q) \lor (P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P \land \neg Q)$.  I think you will understand why this process will *always* work, no matter what the function that needs to be described looks like, and no matter how many atomic propositions are involved.

One last thing: if there is *no* row where the formula is true, then with this process you would not get any terms.  However, this also means that the original formula is a contradiction, and we can always describe a contradiction with $P \land \neg P$ .. which *is* in DNF.

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes perfect sense, i could not imagine any better explanation than this! 

Regards Chris

Comment: @Chris You're welcome!  Have fun in Discrete Mathematics ... one of my favorite courses .. especially the logic part! :)

Comment: Thank you very much i am really looking forward to when we really begin.